# Passing BibteX options in Vim-Latex

Tags: windows, bash, vim, latex, git-bash

My current Latex workflow involves using Mendeley to automatically create .bib files. These bibfiles are stored in a Mendeley directory in my home folder. Because I don't want to have all my projects in this folder, I used to have the following bibtex command in TeXstudio
`bibtex --include-directory="C:\Users\xxx\Mendeley" %`. Recently I have installed Git for windows, and since I liked the Git Bash, have been toying around with Vim and the Vim-Latex suite. Having seen it for a while, I want to start using it for production work.

In my .vimrc file I tried to set up bibtex as such (probably should use ftplugin file for this)

```
let g:Tex_CompileRule_bib='bibtex --include-directory="C:\Users\xxx\Mendeley" $*'
```

I feel like I have used every combination of escaping the "", using Windows/Unix file path and expressions that should expand to the filename. But my bibtex.log keeps showing this:

```
2020-06-01 11:27:41,404+0200 INFO  bibtex - this process (13648) started by 'bash' with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9a\miktex\bin\x64\bibtex.exe" Report
2020-06-01 11:27:41,442+0200 INFO  bibtex - this process (13648) finishes with exit code 1
```

i.e. The `--include-directory` argument does not get passed to Bibtex. Similar .vimrc definitions like `let g:Tex_ViewRule_dvi='yap -1 -s ""'` do manage to pass their arguments. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just in case you don't find a solution for this, another approach could be to add the directory of the bib file to your texmf tree. This way your tex distribution will automatically search it to find the file. (how this is done will depend on which tex distribution you have)

Comment: Thank you for that idea! This requires no further configuration of any editor right? My current workaround is using symlinks, but it is no real solution.

Comment: Yes, this would solve the problem on the tex level - it won't matter which editor you use. Which tex distribution do you have?

Comment: I am using MikTex, so will fix it via the Admin GUI, that is easy enough. I might post this question to the vim stackoverflow or on github, I am now quite curious and want to know why my method didn't work.